# $P(A_1 \cap A_2 |B)=P(A_1|B)P(A_2|B)$ implies $P(A_1|A_2 \cap B)=P(A_1|B)$

Tags: probability, analysis, conditional-probability

i want to prove this:

$P(A_1 \cap A_2 /B)=P(A_1/B)P(A_2/B) $$\Rightarrow $$P(A_1/A_2 \cap B)=P(A_1/B)$

i did for $A_2 \cap B \neq \emptyset$ .but i am  stuck in case  $A_2 \cap B = \emptyset$

i want to see why
$P(A_1 \cap A_2 /B)=P(A_1/B)P(A_2/B) $means that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conditionally independent given $B$.

can you help me?

Comment: $P(A_1/A_2 \cap B)$ is not defined when $A_2\cap B$ is empty.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks